# C++ Inline methods for performance

Tags: c++, performance, inline

I was told long ago to make short functions/methods that are called often inline, by using the keyword ***inline*** and writing the body in the header file.
This was to optimize the code so there would be no overhead for the actual function call.

How does it look with that today? Does modern compilers (Visual Studio 2010's in this case) inline such short functions automatically or is it still "necessary" to do so yourself?

Comment: "*Either with the keyword inline or by writing the body in the header file.*" I think you mean with the keyword `inline` _and_ writing the body in a header -- doing either one without doing both will cause linker errors if you have multiple translation units.

Comment: Of course. I'll edit my question.

Comment: It really is a matter of size: If you call functions very often (like several million times) the function call overhead matters. I actually had one situation in which the function had a simple `if ( something ) return;` at the beginning. The compiler was not able to inline it (or chose not to) and moving this if statement out of the function had a big impact on performance. However the function was called roughly 20 million times before the change. And it was indeed a modern compiler with optimization enabled. So in general: Don't waste your time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`inline` has always been a **hint** to the compiler, and these days compilers for the most part make their own decisions in this regard (see `register`).

In order to expand a function inline, the compiler has to have seen the definition of that function. For functions that are defined and used in only one translation unit, that's no problem: put the definition somewhere before it's used, and the compiler will decide whether to inline the function.

For functions that are used in more than one translation unit, in order for the compiler to see the definition of the function, the definition has to go in a header file. When you do that, you need to mark the function `inline` to tell the compiler and linker that it's okay that there's more than one definition of that function. (well, I suppose you could make the function `static`, but then you could end up wasting space with multiple copies)

Answer (score 4):

Enable warning [C4710](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd3056cz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), this will warn you if a function which you define as inline is not inlined by the compiler.

Enable warning [C4711](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k402bt7y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), this will warn you if the compiler inlines a function not designated for inlining.

The combination of these two warnings will give you a better understanding of what the compiler is actually doing with your code and possibly whether it is worth designating inline functions manually or not.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, the `inline` keyword is used more now to allow you to "violate" the one definition rule when you define a function in a header than to give the compiler a hint about inlining. Many compilers are getting really good at deciding when to inline functions or not, as long as the function body is visible at th4e point of call.

Of course if you define the function only in a source file non-inline, the compiler will be able to inline it in that one source file but not in any other translation unit.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the ODR, but I think the real answer to the OP's question revolves around LTO.

Comment: Actually gcc has -flto which does such things afaik

Comment: @stefan -flto is for link-time optimization. It has nothing to do with the one definition rule. Mark's answer is correct; enabling "violations" (but not really) of the ODR is the core of what `inline` does. "Inlining" is an extra benefit. Re the "but not really": The `inline` keyword modifies rather than eliminates the one definition rule. `inline int foo () {return 0}` in file a.cpp and `inline int foo () {return 1}` in file b.cpp violates the one definition rule. All of the definitions of `inline int foo()` must be identical or the code is still in violation of the ODR.

Answer (score 2):

Inlining may be done by a compiler in the following situations:

1. You marked the function as `inline` and

   1. it's defined in a current translation unit or in file that it's included in it;
   2. compiler decides that it's worth doing so. According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx)

> The `inline` keyword tells the compiler that inline expansion is *preferred*.
>   The compiler treats the inline expansion options and keywords as suggestions.

You used the `__forceinline` keyword (or `__ attribute __((always_inline))` in gcc). This will make compiler to skip some checks and do the inlining for you.

> The `__forceinline` keyword overrides the cost/benefit analysis and relies on the judgment of the programmer instead.

Microsoft compiler can also perform *cross module inlining* if you have turned on [link time code generation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xbf3tbeh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) by passing `/GL` flag to the compiler or `/LTCG` to the linker. It's quite clever in making such optimizations: try to examine the assembly code of modules compiled with `/LTCG`.

Please note, that inlining will never happen if your function is:

- a recursive one;
- called through a pointer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, modern compilers will (depending on various configuration options) automatically choose to inline functions, even if they're in the source (not header) file.  Using the inline directive can give a hint.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from your main point (what amount of placing inline instructions in code is useful as of compilers today), keep in mind that inline functions are just a hint to the compiler, and are not necessarily being compiled as inline.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes, compilers will decide whether or not your function becomes `inline`. You can check this question:

[Does the compiler decide when to inline my functions (in C++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204975/does-the-compiler-decide-when-to-inline-my-functions-in-c)